# JPanel not showing until JFrame is expanded

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, visible

This makes no sense to me. I have a fully working login screen called from my main class, the problem is the JPanel used to hold text areas etc. will not show up until I click the edge of the window (To expand it)

Here is my code:

#### Main

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

public class SchoolSystem
{

public static void main (String [] args)
{

     Login lg = new Login();

}
}
```

#### Login

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

 public class Login extends JFrame implements ActionListener
 {


 JFrame frame;

 JButton SUBMIT;
 JPanel panel;
 JLabel label1,label2;
 public Menus m = new Menus();
 final JTextField  text1,text2;

  {
      frame = new JFrame("Welcome");
      frame.setSize(310,110);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      label1 = new JLabel();
      label1.setText("User ID:");
      text1 = new JTextField(15);

      label2 = new JLabel();
      label2.setText("Password:");
      text2 = new JPasswordField(15);

      SUBMIT=new JButton("LOGIN");

      panel=new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
      panel.add(label1);
      panel.add(text1);
      panel.add(label2);
      panel.add(text2);
      panel.add(SUBMIT);
      add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
      SUBMIT.addActionListener(this);
      text2.addActionListener(this);
      setTitle("Welcome");
      frame.add(panel);
  }


 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
      {
          //Gets the text inside the User ID and Password Panels
          String value1=text1.getText();
          String value2=text2.getText();

          //Compare text to actual ID and password, Act accordingly
          //In this case show a Menu for the Head Teacher
          if ((value1.equals("Admin") && value2.equals("1234"))){
          m.adminMenu();
          frame.setVisible(false);
          }
          else{
          if (value1.equals("Teach") && value2.equals("0000")) {
          m.teacherMenu();
          frame.setVisible(false);
          }

          else{
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Incorrect login or password",
          "Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
          }
          }
      }

 }
```

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 3):

- `frame.setVisible(true);` must be last code line, after all `JComponents` are added to the `JFrame`
- last code lines could be `frame.pack();` and `frame.setVisible(true);`
- use `JDialog` for this job instead of `JFrame`,
- best of could be to use `CardLayout` (call `JFrame.pack()` after switching from `logon panel` to `another panel(s)`)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, `frame.setVisible(true)` should be the last line of code. However, if you want to leave the code as is, then you should call `frame.revalidate()` at the end of your GUI code, right before the closing brace of the initializer block.